# Why this inside friend global function cannot work?

Tags: c++, templates, friend

```
template<class T, class M>
struct myPair{
    friend myPair<T, M> my_make_pair(T f, M s){
        myPair<T, M> tmp(f, s);
        return tmp;
    }
    T first;
    M second;
    myPair(){};
    myPair(T f, M s){
        this->first = f;
        this->second = s;
    }
};

int main(){
    myPair<string, int> a = my_make_pair("hello", 2);
    cout << a.first << " " << a.second << endl;
}
```

the error saids: "my_make_pair" was now declare in this scope. But why and how to ?? Really confused.....

Answer (score 1):

A friend defined inside the class is only found by [argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), but `my_make_pair("hello", 2)` has no argument of type `myPair`. So doesn't work.

The function doesn't really have to be a friend, so could be just a free function (outside the class):

```
template<class T, class M>
myPair<T, M> my_make_pair(T f, M s){
    myPair<T, M> tmp(f, s);
    return tmp;
}
```

That function *will* be found, but ... as `"hello"`is not a `std::string`, the call would return the wrong type of pair anyway.

You *could* get the assignment to work by explicitly specifying the types:

```
myPair<std::string, int> a = my_make_pair<std::string, int>("hello", 2);
```

but that kind of takes away the usefulness of *having* a make-function. You could then just as well construct the pair directly, using the constructor:

```
myPair<std::string, int> a {"hello", 2};
```

Comment: Thanks to BoP and stack-overflow。What a nice answer and I got it.